# $f^{(n)}(x)>\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Check if there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, infinitely differentiable, so that exists $\alpha >0$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)>\alpha,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall  n\in \mathbb{N}. $

I was thinking at $e^x$, because $e^{x}>\lim_{x\rightarrow  -\infty }e^{-x}=0$, but I couldn't find a number $\alpha$ verifying the property above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f'(x) > \alpha > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then for $x<0$ we have 
$$ f(x) = f(0) - \int_x^0 f'(t) dt < f(0) + \alpha x \xrightarrow{x \to -\infty} -\infty, $$
contradicting $f(x) > \alpha$. Therefore there is no such function.